# Django Admin - save_model method ignore saving

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to override django UserAdmin save_model method. 
In some case I want to ignore saving data, but it always save data. Am I missing something. Here my code

```
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        attrs = request.POST

        role=attrs.getlist('userProfile_user-0-role',None)
        if change:
            if int(role[0]) == 1:
                super(MyUserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Subscriptions cannot be changed.")
                # In this case I did not want save data
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you register your admin class to model? Btw, you should probably also call super method if it is not a change.

Comment: Unregister the default admin and then register the your custom.

Comment: Maybe int(role[0]) is always 1.